# Video not showing in iframe on IE, but showing on firefox and chrome

Tags: html, iframe, amazon-s3

The src of iframe is a URL to a video. Every time when the page is loaded, it asked me whether to save or open the video. But the video show well on firefox and chrome. When the URL points to video on youtube, it works too. Anyone has the same problem? My IE is 11. But it should work on most IE versions.

```
<iframe width="550" height="400" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you need to support old browsers? If not, the HTML5 `<video>` element will do.

Comment: Thanks. I need to support youtube embed video too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373250/html-video-tag-display-youtube-video

Comment: You can't do that for YouTube videos. You have to use YouTube's embed feature, which is under the video in the share section.