# HTML video tag display Youtube video

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I got some youtube urls, such as https://www.youtube.com/embed/LaXGkW_-Nvc?list=RDTDDDvaoGiDg. When I put it to html video tag, it said "Invalid source".

How to solve this problem?

When I used iframe to display videos, I had another problem as described here: [Video not showing in iframe on IE, but showing on firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371847/video-not-showing-in-iframe-on-ie-but-showing-on-firefox-and-chrome).

This is my HTML:

```
<video width="300" height="auto" autoplay="" controls="" name="media"><source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LaXGkW_-Nvc?list=RDTDDDvaoGiDg"></video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the HTML5 video tag for youtube videos, it only supports files that are either MP4, WebM and Ogg. [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Youtube already provides you with an "embed" function on their page which auto generates the iFrame for you. [Youtube Embed](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en) There are a few other methods but they are no longer used (deprecated). [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player)

As for the issue with IE, maybe have a look at this similar question: [YouTube iframe embed code not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199683/youtube-iframe-embed-code-not-working-in-ie7-or-in-ie-compatability-mode)

The only way around the issue if you want to use the HTML5 video tag is to download the Youtube video in one of the specified formats.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<iframe>` tag to embed the YouTube. Please read the code below:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5L3wKniOnro?autoplay=1" width="600" height="400" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```